# After hosting to server symfony gives 500 internal server error

Tags: symfony, ftp, upload

After putting my project online, nothing appears, a blank page or an error HTTP ERROR 500 appears..

I do not know what to do, if someone would have helped please ..

I have already done the following:

```
composer install
asset:install
```

I will respond as quickly as possible to your answers

Comment: What version of PHP and Symfony are you using? Is there anything in the logs, perhaps? :)

Comment: Symfony 3 and PHP 5.5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had the same problem with Symfony 3, and the solution was in app.php :

In my case it was because of bootstrap.php.cache that it was not displayed.

Comment this part in your file:

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

Besides, I did not understand why.

Comment: ow !!! You are right ! I do not understand why it does that, but commenting on this line worked :D

Comment: I think there's a reason for that, but I'm still looking for the right answer to that concern ^^

Answer (score 0):

If the project done with php language and you upload the file to server.

Sometime file and folder permission give this error.

Please check out the file permission to 644 and folder permission to 755.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, all folders must have 755 permission, and 644 for files?

Comment: Yes you can check it out as first step to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had sam problem. You have to chmod cache directory of Symfony.

Comment: I set the permissions to 777 but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you checked all the previous answers suggestions, and all are ok, then I can think at the following:

- check to see if you've copied on the server the `web/.htaccess` file. I think this needs to have `0644` as privileges.
- if you've copied it, but still getting 500, then that might be because you have an error in your source code, and, the easiest way to check if there are any source code errors, just edit, in your PC, the `web/app_dev.php` file, and comment out these lines of code:

  ```
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
      || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
      || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
  ) {
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
      exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
  }
  ```

and upload it into the `web` directory on the server, then access the homepage of the website, in the `dev` mode, using `/app_dev.php` in front. 
This will check for any error.

But be aware that, after ending this task, you need to de-comment the above lines of code in the `app_dev.php` file, and re-upload it to the server, as the last part of the code of this file **should not** be executed on the remote server.

Comment: When I comment on the code piece identical to the one above, and I go to `www.domain.com/app_dev.php` , it shows me my page well. And when I try to pass on other pages my queries work well. But only when `app_dev.php` is present in the URL

Comment: I can access all my pages, and my app in full with `app_dev.php` , I just do a test online. But in prod it does not work